# How do i get "score" to show up in the game window?

Tags: python, pygame

So far in my snake game the score is printed in python shell. How can i have it printed in the games window instead? So that the game and the score are in the same window?
Thanks Eric

```
while running:


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    worm.move()
    worm.draw()
    food.draw()

    if worm.crashed:
        exit();
    elif worm.x <= 0 or worm.x >= w -1:
        running = False
    elif worm.y <= 0 or worm.y >= h-1:
        running = False
    elif worm.position() == food.position():
        score += 1
        worm.eat()
        print " score: %d" % score
        food = Food(screen)
    elif food.check(worm.x, worm.y):
        score += 1
        worm.eat()
        print "score: %d" % score
        food = Food(screen)
    elif running == False:
        exit();

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            worm.event(event)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)
```

Edit-

```
while running:


screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
worm.move()
worm.draw()
food.draw()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.get_fonts() 

if worm.crashed:
    exit();
elif worm.x <= 0 or worm.x >= w -1:
    running = False
elif worm.y <= 0 or worm.y >= h-1:
    running = False

elif food.check(worm.x, worm.y):
    score += 1
    worm.eat()
    food = Food(screen)
    message = 'score: %d' % score
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    text = font.render(message, 1, white)
    screen.blit(text, (50, 50))

elif running == False:
    exit();

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.quit:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        worm.event(event)
```

Why isnt the Score Apearing, im not getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [font](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) module to render fonts on screen.

From the userguide:

```
white = (255, 255, 255)

message = 'your message'
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
text = font.render(message, 1, white)
screen.blit(text, (x_position,y_position))
```

Comment: Thanks i figured the rest out myself

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edit:  You're only blitting the text to the screen when you take that particular elif branch (i.e, only when the worm gets the food).  On the next frame, you clear the screen, but the food isn't there, so the score doesn't get drawn.  You should blit the score to the screen every frame, instead.